# Converting a date to a calendar quarter

Tags: replacement, date-and-time, rule

I have a list that includes dates.  I need to convert each date to be the last day of the quarter that it's in.  So for example I want {2013,7,1,0,0,0} to become {2013,9,30,0,0,0}.  Actually I don't need the zero's.  I was trying to do this with a rule, but ran into problems.  I wanted a rule like: 7,_ -> 9,30.  Further I was going to try to insert alternatives into this with something like 7,_ |8,_ |9,_ -> 9,30.

Is there a way to write a rule to handle this?  Or, for this specific problem is there a better way to convert these dates to quarter end dates?

An example of a row of data is:  {{2009,5,1,0,0,0},"TYAU145A", 92468., 0.5, 46234.}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating function `endq` :-

```
endq = DateList[{#1, 1 + 3 Ceiling[#2/3], 0}] &;

endq @@ {2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}
```

> {2013, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0.}

For example, with data :-

```
a = {{{2009, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "TYAU145A", 92468., 0.5, 46234.},
    {{2012, 8, 12, 0, 0, 0}, "TYAU145A", 92468., 0.5, 46234.},
    {{2001, 12, 9, 0, 0, 0}, "TYAU145A", 92468., 0.5, 46234.}};

{endq @@ #1, ##2} & @@@ a
```

> {{{2009, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, "TYAU145A", 92468., 0.5, 46234.},
>     {{2012, 9, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, "TYAU145A", 92468., 0.5, 46234.},
>     {{2001, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, "TYAU145A", 92468., 0.5, 46234.}}

Alternatively, using a rule :-

```
qrule = {y_, m_, __} :> DateList[{y, 1 + 3 Ceiling[m/3], 0}];

{# /. qrule, ##2} & @@@ a
```

Comment: I'm still working on your "endq" solution.  I don't understand how it works.  I see how it gets the year and the month if I understand how the slots work.  How does it get the last day of the month?  Although I'm really not sure how any of it works.  I assumed endq @@ replaces List with the endq function.  I can understand how one head is replaced by another head, say Plus @@.  I'm really not seeing what happens.  Using FullForm or Hold didn't help me very much, probably because I'm not that facile with them either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @MitchellKaplan - Hi, I'm using `Apply` (`@@`) to pick up the numbered slot arguments, e.g. `{#1, #2} & @@ {2013, 6, 30}`.  The month end calculation is done by `DateList` : setting the day to zero steps back a day, so `DateList[{2013, 7, 0}]` finds the last day of June.  Likewise `DateList[{2013, 14, 0}]` finds the last day of January.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a lot from this, although I'll have to play with slots some more to fully get it.

Answer (score 4):

```
quarterfy[{y_, m_, _, z___}] :=
 Switch[m,
  1 | 2 | 3, {y, 3, 31, z},
  4 | 5 | 6, {y, 6, 30, z},
  7 | 8 | 9, {y, 9, 30, z},
  10 | 11 | 12, {y, 12, 31, z}
  ]

quarterfy@{2013, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0}
(* {2013, 9, 30, 0, 0, 0}  *)
```